# How to implement new changes in live wordpress website?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have my live online shopping website running on aws machine, I want to add new products, posts, and blog to my live website without affecting the customer and customer order. I am using the woocommerce plugin for selling my products online. Importing the local site to live website will overwrite my customer information and orders. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is there a reason for not adding new content directly to your live site? You can leave it as a `draft` or `for review` rather than publishing it and that why you don't have to worry about any issues with your local site changes overwriting your live site.

You can also try the [wordpress exporter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-exporter/) for migrating products/posts/pages from one to the other.

Personally, I'd recommend making any content specific changes directly to the live site so you don't have to stress about database conflicts.

Comment: Please go through how to update url in wordpress. There will be number of DB updates . Woocommerce product is also a post .